# Calling from a Java thread to JNI and back to a requestPermissions

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, java-threads

I have the following problem.
I have a Java function inside a thread that loops forever, then a JNI API which eventually calls a static function in another class.
This static function is trying to make a call to requestPermissions in order to show the request permission popup, and while the user accepts or rejects, this thread sleeps. The popup is showing up and the user cand respond to it, but the function **onRequestPermissionsResult** is never called.
Is there any way to sort this issue?

What am I doing wrong?

I mean if I don't sleep on the UI thread this should not block it am I right?
The popup is showing up, but the answer never arrives.

This is the **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
    
    class MyThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //JNI_CALL();
            MainActivity.AskForPermissionsFromJNI();
        }
    }

    static FragmentActivity myActivityStoredInAStaticVariable;
    static boolean OnRequestPermission=false;
    MyThread mThread;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle aSavedInstanceState) {
        mThread = new MyThread();
        myActivityStoredInAStaticVariable = this;
        mThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
         //This function is never called WHY?
         //Do what you need to do
         OnRequestPermission=true;
    }

    public static void AskForPermissionsFromJNI()
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(myActivityStoredInAStaticVariable, new String[]{"android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"} , 1234);
        
        //Wait until onRequestPermissionsResult ended
        while (!OnRequestPermission) {try { Thread.sleep(100); } catch(Exception e) {}}
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
The JNI is not part of the problem, if I just replace the JNI call on the static function happen the same
<strike>This is the **JNI.cpp**</strike>

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_dle_application_MainActivity_JNI_CALL( JNIEnv* env )
{
    //Call Back to Java
    ...
    dispatch_java_method(AskForPermissionsFromJNI);
    ...
}
```

Comment: From what I've seend the JNI is not part of the problem, if i just do that without the jni part happens the same.

Comment: `while (true) {try { Thread.sleep(100); } catch(Exception e) {}}` doesn't "Wait until onRequestPermissionsResult ended". It blocks **forever**.

Comment: @talex Whoops. I thought the try-catch was around the while loop.

Comment: Ok what about now?

Comment: Do you get the callback if you remove the `while` loop? Why can't you signal to the native code that you have a result when you get the result, instead of blocking that thread for the whole duration? Also, the assignment to `myActivityStoredInAStaticVariable` looks like it should go before `mThread.start()`.

Comment: Yes, I get the callback if I remove the while loop, but I want the call to that function to be syncronous.

Comment: Strange... this setup works for me on Nexus 5 with API 23. Having said this, I must remind you that you have potential memory leaks in your code: **myActivityStoredInAStaticVariable** should be a weak reference, and **MyThread** inner class should be static.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally managed to handle this running the request permission inside the main loop the following way:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    myActivityStoredInAStaticVariable.requestPermissions(new String[]{"android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"}, 1234);
                }
            }
        });
```